# Why IDEA tells me that it doesn't support java 12?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am a freshman in java and recently I am learning java and framework related to it. I created a simple Maven project in IDEA 2019.3 and there was no error during compilation. However, when I started to run the project, IDEA told me that they didn't support java 12. It also confused me that after I changed java version to java 11 or java 8, IDEA told me to use java 7 or latest version.What's wrong with my problem?

[image: the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which version do you have in:
File / Settings / Build, Execution, Development / Compiler / Java Compiler

And in File / Project structure check the Project and Modules tab.

You might have a different java version selected there.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked my java version. But all of  version settings are java 12. Maybe I need install java 8 or 11 instead of java 12?

Comment: I have 8, 11 and 12 installed but having only java 12 should work. Make sure the `Target bytecode version` is also 12 in the  File / Settings / Build, Execution, Development / Compiler / Java Compiler

Answer (score 0):

check:

1. File -> Project Structure -> modules -> language level/module sdk
2. File -> Project Structure -> SDKs